# Printer via USB

Tags: printing

I am trying to add my HP printer to my Ubuntu. When I click on the "printers icon" in the settings, nothing happen. I am new to Ubuntu and I have no idea how to fix this. I tried to use hplib and if I type hpsetup I got this:

```
No command    'hpsetup' found, did you mean:
Command 'hp-setup' from package 'hplip' (main)
hpsetup: command not found    so I typed hp-setup and I got this
```

So I tried hp-setup and I got

```
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 545, in main
known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 272, in addusersitepackages
user_site = getusersitepackages()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 247, in getusersitepackages
user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 237, in getuserbase
USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 578, in get_config_var
return get_config_vars().get(name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 524, in get_config_vars
_init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 408, in _init_posix
from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
from _sysconfigdata_nd import *
ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd
```

Which I have no idea at all what does this means and what to do...
Any help...

Comment: Try this http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a pretty easy set of ways to install HP printers in Ubuntu.  What I's suggest first for a new user, is a graphic method using Ubuntu's tools.

Open the Settings program (click the 'gear' in the top right corner, and settings is the third entry in the menu) and look for the printers icon - there is a little Add button in the top left corner of the window which pops up, allowing you to add a printer.  It will scan for printers, so you should have your printer hooked up and powered on.

---

If you are more adventurous, and would like to install from the command line there are a couple of things you have to do:

Open a terminal window (press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)

Ubuntu 15.10 does not have the following program fully installed, so it needs to be removed and re-installed:

```
sudo apt-get remove hplip
sudo apt-get install --install-suggests hplip
```

Now the hpsetup program can be executed

`hp-setup`

This will open a set of terminal windows which guide you through the process of connecting the HP printer.

Comment: The problem is when I click on the "printers" icon, nothing happened! I tried the terminal one and if I type hpsetup I got this:

Comment: Please look at my edited post @charlesGreen

Comment: The errors mean that the python libraries were not fully installed in your computer.  please execute the command `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic`, and try again

Comment: Update for Ubuntu bionic, in 2022:

`sudo apt-get install --install-suggests hplip`

returns:

```
Need to get 6467 MB of archives.
After this operation, 22.8 GB of additional disk space will be used.
```

I think I'll look for a Raspberry-Pi which can print to an HP printer for less than 22GB of HD space...

Comment: @axello Yes, the [HPLip program](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/hplip) set does include quite a bit of stuff, most of which will not be used by most people, such as the CUPS print system, and the SANE scanner interface.  Additionally if not already installed, it used libc6, and python3, and a graphical interface.